# Jersey WADL generator support custom annotations

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, wadl

I am trying to implement a custom WadlGenerator and I want to add a custom annotation to a method of a resource. Example:

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Path("myPath")
@customAnnotation(attribute="value")
public synchronized
```

My problem is that I don't know how to access this custom annotation while generating the WADL. I tried to override a WadlGenerator Implementation like "WadlGeneratorJAXBGrammarGenerator". I already found this post on how to make a custom annotation for an attribute here: [custom parameter annotation](http://developcorner.blogspot.de/2013/01/custom-wadl-generator-in-jersey.html). 
Does anyone know how to get the annotation from a method? Or is there even an easier way to add custom annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to override the createMethod of the WADL generator I was using:

```
public class MyWADLGEnerator extends WadlGeneratorApplicationDoc {
@Override
public Method createMethod(org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.Resource ar, ResourceMethod arm) {
    Method method = super.createMethod(ar, arm);

    Annotation[] annotations = arm.getInvocable().getDefinitionMethod().getAnnotations();
```

By doing this, I can get all the annotations which are declared to the methods.